# Local object memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiimageview

I'm implementing an application in Objective-C, and just start to analyze it. It looks like I've got some problems with some images. For example, I've wrote:

```
Example = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 70, 290, 98.5)];
UIImage * ImageExample = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.png"];
Example.image = ImageExample;
[ImageExample release];
[Menu addSubview:Example];
[Example release];
```

It gives me:

> Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller

I've found some example, with `NSString` that made it local, and release after using.

So what's the matter with this sort of code please?

Comment: Please use ARC unless you have a very good reason not to. Legitimate reasons not to use ARC are hard to come by nowadays.

Comment: Well I guess it is a good thing to try to live without ARC to understand how memory management works. But I'm agree that it's better to use ARC "in real world".

Comment: I would suggest you to look into [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) and [naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 UIImage * ImageExample = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.png"];
```

gives autorelease object, You can not release it as you are not allocating(owned) it .

Answer (score 0):

You don't own ImageExample. So you shouldn't release it. Take a look at this guide:
[iOS Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)
Especially on the article "Basic Memory Management Rules".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below statement, It should work fine.

```
[ImageExample release];
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

You should only release objects you OWN.

<strike>You only release objects that you have allocated memory for. So, the thumb rule is - use release only if you have used init.</strike>

Also, starting with iOS5? Apple gave us something called as ARC (Automatic reference Counting). Just make sure the checkbox is ticked when creating the project. With ARC you don't have to use release statements at all. The complier will do the job for you.

While ARC simplifies a lot of things, you can also make mistakes with it. I would recommend you to have a read about [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) whenever you are comfortable with coding in Objective C. Have a look at the WWDC session videos related to ARC too.

Comment: I meant -  you should use release only on objects you OWN. In this case I was just referring to the OP's example of initWithFrame. In hindsight I guess, I should have been more precise.